# how to write properly git pull or git push?

Tags: git

**EDITED**

**the names of the local branch and the remote branch are different**

I am now on the branch "fixbug", tracking the remote branch "develop"

```
git checkout -b fixbug remotes/origin/develop
```

My branches look like this:

```
git branch -a

  master
* fixbug
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/develop
```

I am now on the local branch "fixbug" tracking from the remote branch "remotes/origin/develop" so which git push is correct?

```
git push origin develop
```

or

```
git push origin/develop
```

or

```
git push remotes/origin/develop
```

I follow some people's suggestion "**git push origin develop**", and this is the result:

```
git push origin develop
error: src refspec develop does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to ... servername
```

```
git status
On branch fixBugTime
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

and if I just "git push", the result is

```
git push
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:develop

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin fixBugTime
```

Comment: use the first one

Comment: You omitted the option of `git push`.

Comment: For God’s sake, please [look up stuff like](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) [this in the manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)!

Comment: Sorry, my case is different. I've just edited. I tried to delete this question and want to post another question, but failed.

Comment: Post the contents of the repository’s `.git/config` (blank the URLs as necessary)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The local branch is **fixbug**, but the remote branch is **develop**. When we push, Git is concerning if we want to create a new remote branch "fixbug" or push to the "develop". Actually, Git does notice the similarity of names, though.

So there are 2 ways to push correctly:

1) rename the local branch "fixbug" to "develop"

```
git checkout fixbug
git branch -m "develop"
git push origin develop
```

2) or push to the develop directly in an appropriate name:

```
git checkout fixbug
git push origin HEAD:develop
```

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of the github [Git Cheatsheet](https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf) and consulting it gives the answers needed.

Basically, the first one is correct `git push origin develop`, but it also gives a bit more information.

The `origin` part is just an alias for a remote location, a benefit of the distributed nature of git.  This can be set to just about anything when setting up a remote location, so you could have aliases for the origin repository, an office repository and a backup repository, where you could then choose where to commit or pull from

## Edit - following the change of question scope

If you're in doubt as to what the remote should be, use the `git remote -v` command (see the [git-scm](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) manual for greater detail on this), which will show the remote name for the push and pull remotes for the current branch:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://repository.com/example/develop (fetch)
origin  https://repository.com/example/develop (push)
```

From there, you'll be able to use the first part of that to set the remote alias.  In this case if we wanted to push, we'd go from the line `origin https://repository.com/example/develop (push)` to see that the remote in this case is **origin**.

We can then run "git push origin develop" to push the changes

Comment: now, the case is different. Could you correct your answer?

Comment: Updated the answer now following the change of question.  It should meet generic requirements as well as this case

Answer (score 0):

Push the changes to the right branch

```
git push origin fixbug
```

then step into develop

```
git checkout develop
```

then pull the changes

```
git pull origin fixbug
```

then merge, commit and push to develop

```
git push origin develop
```

Comment: This depends entirely on the push default and the configuration for that branch.

Comment: now, the case is different. Could you correct your answer?

Comment: Please take a look on my answer. Thanks